# Using authenticator app with Apple Developer Console

Tags: developer-program

Our company has phone numbers associated with our Apple Developer account but we need to switch that to using an authenticator app as it is difficult to rely on team member phones to be available at all times.

Is it possible to switch to using an authenticator app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, (not in June 2022) but you can add multiple accounts to your developer team and then each person can choose their own best auth method.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

We have a VOIP group call number as our secondary phone and that works well with Microsoft Teams, but adding trusted devices is the way to go for the most equivalent to an “Authenticator with rolling passcodes or a Yubikey type device” experience.

Perhaps when [Passkeys](https://developer.apple.com/passkeys/) ships, you will have more options.